# Firebase Realtime Database rules for specific node of structure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Before creating a new user I want to check if creating `username` property already exists in Firebase Database.

Checking function is:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: loginRegisterTextField.text).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
   if snapshot.exists() {
       print("Login exists") 
   } else {
       print("Login does not exist")
  }
})
```

JSON is:

[image]

Rules are for node `users`:

```
{
  "rules": {
        
    "users" : { 
      ".read": "auth != null",

          "$uid" : {
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        }
    },
```

Is it possible to write a rules to check existing of `username` without a new `uid`?

Comment: The `username` child node you're using has nothing to do with a UID, and in fact, doesn't have anything to do with rules either. The problem with this code flow is that, in order to check to see if a username exists, the user must be authenticated, but if this is a new user, they are not yet authenticated, so that won't work. One option is to create the firebase account first (which authenticates the user) *then* ask them to create a username. In that scenario, your code will work pretty much as is. Otherwise you can keep a publicly accessible username list, or leverage cloud functions.

Comment: @Jay Thanks, I've the same thought to create a new readable branch with usernames but I hoped until the last don't do it)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check for a specific **value** across a JSON branch in security rules. This has been covered quite a few times before, so I recommend checking some of these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%20unique).

But you *can* make your query on `/users` more secure, by only allowing that specific query, and not allowing people to read all of `/users`. To [secure the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) you could some something like:

```
{
  "rules": {     
    "users" : { 
      ".read": "auth != null && 
                query.orderByChild == 'username' &&
                query.equalTo !== null",
      ...
```

This is the first time I've used `query.equalTo !== null`, so there may be some small mistakes in that part, but the flow should be clear.

Comment: I think the OP wants to check if the username exists *before* creating the Firebase user (they mentioned no uid) and if that's the case, the user won't be auth'd yet. I may be reading the question wrong though.

Comment: Ah, that's a good point Jay. In that case, they can remove the `auth != null` part from the `.read` rule on `/users` and still only allow the specific query that they code uses.

Comment: @Jay you are right, I want to check if the username exists before creating the Firebase user

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for another point of view to my problem.

Comment: @StanislavPutilov As said in my comment above, if you remove `auth != null && ` from the rules I shared, even unauthenticated users can perform the username query - but that's all they can do then.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, I get it